# Is it possible to exclude certain fields using JSONATA?

Tags: jsonata

Using JSONATA, is it possible to exclude certain fields that are nested in a deep structure without using object construction? For example, with the following object

```
{
    "collection": [
        {
            "id": "ABC",            
            "learningunit": {
                "metadata": {
                    "show": true,
                    "unitType": {
                        "code": "U",                        
                        "value": "Unit"
                    }                   
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "UYE",            
            "learningunit": {
                "metadata": {
                    "show": false,
                    "unitType": {
                        "code": "C",                        
                        "value": "COURSE"
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

can we exclude the field "show" and "value" in order to get the following result.

```
{
    "collection": [
        {
            "id": "ABC",            
            "learningunit": {
                "metadata": {                   
                    "unitType": {
                        "code": "U"                     
                    }                   
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "UYE",            
            "learningunit": {
                "metadata": {                   
                    "unitType": {
                        "code": "C"                     
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

FYI, the following object construction expression does the job but it is cumbersome to write if the object is complex.

```
{"collection":collection.
    {
    "id": id,
    "learningunit": learningunit.
        { 
            "metadata": metadata. 
            {
                "unitType": unitType.
                {
                    "code": code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [transform operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform) and remove all 'value' and 'show' fields from the nested structure:

```
$$ ~> | ** | {}, ['show', 'value'] |
```

See it on the live Stedi playground: https://stedi.link/Usc1tpg

Note that if you need to clear those on a specific path only, you can also do it more surgically:

```
$$
  ~> | *.learningunit.metadata | {}, ['show'] |
  ~> | *.learningunit.metadata.unitType | {}, ['value'] |
```

Playground: https://stedi.link/Bh8cUiM